# How to get rid of duplicated images and insert only new ones

Tags: javascript, angular

I wanted to upload images, I used an array named images to store the file and urls of images that I have chosen, an array named listUrl to store just the urls of chosen images (to compare with url from selected files). The array "images" and "selectedFiles" have the same structure ([{file, url}, {file, url},...]). I don't know what is wrong with my code, I can log selectedFiles but cannot log selectedFiles[i], please help me solve this

Here is my html file

```
<input type="file" multiple (change)="onSelectedFile($event)"/>
```

Here is my javascript file

```
images = [];
onSelectedFile(e){
    let listUrl = this.images.map(image => image["url"]);
    const files = e.target.files;
    let selectedFiles = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e =>
        selectedFiles.push({ file: files[i], url: reader.result });
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }
    console.log(selectedFiles);
    console.log(selectedFiles.length);
    let fileDistinct = selectedFiles.filter(x => listUrl.indexOf(x.url) < 0);
    if(fileDistinct.length > 0){
      this.images = [...this.images, ...fileDistinct]
    }
}
```

I expect the array fileDistinct has images that differenciate from my original array images

Comment: Maybe the image is not loaded yet, making `selectedFiles[i]` unavailable. Can you confirm the images are being loaded inside the `render.onload` function?

Comment: yes, the image is loaded